# How to tokenize a paragraph into words?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a sentence:

```
var input = @"I go to to http://www.google.com.I don't like cats.";
```

I want to try to find all the words in the sentence is. I need to get the string in term of words.

When I do `String stripped = Regex.Replace(input,"\\p{P}", "");`, I get `I go to to httpwwwgooglecomI dont like cats` as expected.

Is there a clever way to get `I go to to http://www.google.com I dont like cats` instead of having to do a lot of `if then` conditions.

My problem is that I do not know how I can detect URLs in a reliable way to be able to treat them as a single word.

Tried lucene here are terms it pulled out:

term=i
term=go
term=http
term=www.google.com.i
term=don't
term=like
term=cats

Comment: Get the string in terms of words? Maybe you mean split the string into words?

Comment: Use [Lucene.Net](https://lucenenet.apache.org/)'s StandardAnalyzer.

Comment: Care to explain the down votes? It's not a simple string split.

Comment: Can you please show the exact desired output, so we know how to make the matcher? For instance, not clear if you'd consider `http` to be a word, etc. If you reply to this message, make sure to start with `@zx81` if you want me to see it.

Comment: @zx81 I have the exact output string I want here: I go to to http://www.google.com I dont like cats

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Just to make sure, you want it as a phrase, right? You don't want a list: `I,go,to,google.com,I,dont,like,cats`... Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current input, you can use this:

```
\b(?:(?<=http://\S*?)(?!www)\w+\.\w+|(?!www)[\w']+(?!://))\b
```

See [the demo](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=a07061d8-7b46-4c64-9a04-908d27895261).

Of course this begs the question "what's an acceptable word", so this expression can be tweaked to varying requirements and conditions.

**In C#:**

```
var myRegex = new Regex(@"\b(?:(?<=http://\S*?)(?!www)\w+\.\w+|(?!www)[\w']+(?!://))\b", RegexOptions.Multiline);
string resultString = myRegex.Match(yourString).Value;
Console.WriteLine(resultString);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay Sam, I got tied up. Finally found the time to post regex with demo and sample code. :)

Answer (score 1):

No there is not a good way to do that as a domain can consist of a varying number of words, all these examples are valid domain names:

- http://bit.ly
- http://visit.my.cool.homepage
- http://hello.you

You could keep a list of top level domains, but as of this year (or last year) anyone with enough money can [buy a top level domain](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/).

However, in your exact case you could parse the string as there are no top level domains with just one character.

Possible solution:

What you could do if you need the solution to be reliable is to try to lookup every domain name. Chances are that the string is too long if you can't find an IP for the domain (= move the last word into a seperate one and try again).

Answer (score 0):

You could first do a split by whitespaces and then a trim for punctuations.

```
char[] separators = new char[] {' ', '\t', '\r', '\n'};
char[] trimchars = new char[] {'.', ','}; 
var input = @"my string with a http://google.com/query url. I only
    want to have words";

var words = input.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x=> x.Trim(trimchars));

foreach (var x in words)
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Comment: You forgot the case when `.I` is directly after the domain name without a space.

Comment: It is absolutely impossible to decide such a case automatically. How do you want to distinguish whether `.I` belongs to the URL or not?